# Order of convergence of Fixed point method .

Tags: reference-request, numerical-methods

I am unable to figure out the proof of Order of convergence of the Fixed point method,

source - http://math.bd.psu.edu/faculty/stevens/Old-Courses/MTHBD423-Fall2003/Notes-Handouts/fixed-point.pdf

[image]

I doubt in page 2 that why = was taken and not $\leq$ ?

Any help guys also if any reference is there where it is lucid kindly suggest !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at point $a)$ second line. Equality is given by the mean value theorem. It is just that.

Comment: I missed it ! thanks.